# 'Failed to compile' error when I try to run my web app

Tags: reactjs, web-applications

[image]

This is a clone web app from: https://github.com/apathre/tinder-clone-webApp

**Failed to compile**

```
./src/auth/auth-helper.js
Line 66:5:   'admin' is not defined  no-undef
Line 69:20:  'admin' is not defined  no-undef
```

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `admin` with `firebase` in lines 66 and 69?

Comment: @AreebKhan did not work